# Allow app to run from Quick Start bar without unlocking (like camera)

Tags: android

If my app is assigned to the Quick Launch bar of the unlock screen, is there some way I can make it so that the user doesn't need to enter their unlock code in order to use the app, in the same way as the camera in Android 4.2?

Comment: take a look at [lock screen widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen)